# Force a new page using PdfBundle in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, pdf

I use the [PdfBundle](https://github.com/psliwa/PdfBundle) (PHPPdf) in Symfony2 and create the PDF using twig like this:

```
<pdf>
    <dynamic-page>
        <placeholders>
           <footer>
                 <div height="50px" width="100%">
                     <page-info font-size="9" font-type="helvetica" format="Page %s of %s" />
                 </div>
             </footer>
        </placeholders>
        <div>
        Some written text in the first page
        </div>

        <!-- Here I want to start always a second page -->

        <div>
        Some written text on the second page
        </div>
    </dynamic-page>
</pdf>
```

I want that the second text is always on a new page, but the numbering in the footer must continue. When I start a new dynamic-page, there is a new page, but the numbering of the sites is gone.

Comment: checked out the library, this seems to be a wrapper around snappy which itself is a wrapper around PHP WkHtmlToPdf .. 
https://github.com/mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf#multi-page-pdf-with-toc-and-cover-page

Comment: Thanks I found the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the solution. I misunderstood the information and thought `page-break` is a attribute, but it is a tag. So I must only set `<page-break />` at the position I want to break the page.

```
<pdf>
    <dynamic-page>
        <placeholders>
           <footer>
                 <div height="50px" width="100%">
                     <page-info font-size="9" font-type="helvetica" format="Page %s of %s" />
                 </div>
             </footer>
        </placeholders>
        <div>
        Some written text in the first page
        </div>

        <page-break />

        <div>
        Some written text on the second page
        </div>
    </dynamic-page>
</pdf>
```

It is also important that the `<page-break />` is a direct children of the `<dynamic-page>`. It can't be in a div or table. They must be closed to set a page break.